# Highcharts asp.net image

Tags: asp.net, highcharts, server-side

I was wondering if there is a way to implement get the image of my current chart in the ASP.net server to provide a consistency in the display between the display and the exported reports.

All I found online was related to using client side script to export data image one by one.
I also found lots of can related to running your own server for security purposes (which is irrelevant to be me).

What I need is to be able to get the images on the server code to include the data in the reports I am generating.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rendering highcharts serverside: http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts

Comment: @Mark Thanks. It works, I am now using Javascript to generate SVG to the server, then convert them to image and add them to PowerPoints.